# How to handle only ClientAbortException?

Tags: java, tomcat, exception

I am coding a download file controller
Sometime user will close the browser window before the file is fully written.  - which is cool.

The problem is that my logs are full of this error:

> org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:333)
>            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:758)
>            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:663)
>            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:368)
>            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:346)
>            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
>            at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2147)
>            at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102)
>            at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123)
>            at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078)

When I am trying to catch only this specific error eclipse is saying:

> ClientAbortException cannot be resolved to a type

I have the project setup and running correctly so is it possible to catch only this specific exception:

```
   org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException
```

I would like to keep the IOException in case of another catastrophe.

[image: try catch structure]

Comment: I highly suggest you include the code we can copy-paste-reproduce easily instead of the image. Or keep the image to highlight what happens, but *include* the code as well.

Comment: Is your code running (catching the ClientAbortException and not logging it)? If not, why? This would help to understand, what kind of help you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ClientAbortException`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ClientAbortException.html) is derived from `IOException`. You have to inspect exactly what exception caused the `IOException e`:

```
...
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    // ... handle FileNotFoundException
} catch (IOException e) {
    String exceptionSimpleName = e.getCause().getClass().getSimpleName();
    if ("ClientAbortException".equals(exceptionSimpleName)) {
        // ... handle ClientAbortException
    } else {
        // ... handle general IOException or another cause
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Not directly because the exception is not thrown directly. You have to use the way I described. Does it work? :))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for a certain class name (that ties your application to a specific servlet container) I usually handle `IOExceptions` on write differently than IOExceptions on read, like so (very pseudo-ish code):

```
try {
  byte[] buffer = ...
  in.read(buffer);
  try {
    out.write(buffer);
  } catch (IOException writeException) {
    // client aborted request
  }
} catch (IOException readException) {
  // something went wrong -> signal 50x or something else
}
```

Worked out quite fine so far.

Answer (score 1):

(As of @Nikolas Charalambidis answer)

- Ignore `"org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException:java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer"`

  > `e.getCause().getClass().getSimpleName()` == "IOException"

  > `e.getMessage()` == "java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer"
- And don't handle general IOException and another cause

  ```
   ...    
   } catch (IOException e) {
       if (! e.getMessage().contains("Connection reset by peer")) {
           throw e;
       }

   } finally {
       close(output);
       close(input);
   }
   ...
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "as of Nikolas' answer". Are you trying to add some additional information on top of Nikolas' answer? On its own, the answer itself isn't too clear. Maybe consider rewriting your bullet points as complete sentences.